# Максимальная длина пароля в Windows

Tags: windows

Подскажите сколько символов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Шифрование файлов в Windows XP](http://forum.izcity.com/index.php?topic=2158.0) - очень интересное обсуждение. Видимо, точно, сколько можно использовать знаков в пароле, знают только мелкомягкие.

Answer (score 2):

Для NTLM-аутентификации - 128 символов. Подробнее: [NTLM user authentication in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102716/en-us).